# How to put holder item value into new array?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I am a beginner in Android development, help me please.
I have a firestore recyclerview adapter, then I want to put each String from the value holder into a new array.

```
@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull OrderHolder holder,
int position, @NonNull OrdertList model)
{
    holder.emailpembeli.setText(model.getEmailPembeli());
    String email = holder.emailpembeli.getText().toString();
    inisialisasidata(email); //call method for pass value
}
```

The method :

```
    private void inisialisasidata(String email) {
        String[]pembeli = new String[]{};
        for (int i = 0; i>=100 ; i++){
              pembeli[i] = email;
        }
     Log.d("OrderAdapter", Arrays.toString(pembeli));
    }
```

I have tried changing email from the string holder to

```
String email = model.getEmailPembeli().toString();
```

But nothing changes and here is my Logcat

> 10-08 05:54:39.716 16106-16106/skripsi.renatta.rintan.skripsipbk D/OrderAdapter: []
>   10-08 05:54:39.786 16106-16106/skripsi.renatta.rintan.skripsipbk D/OrderAdapter: []
>   10-08 05:54:39.870 16106-16106/skripsi.renatta.rintan.skripsipbk D/OrderAdapter: []
>   10-08 05:54:39.972 16106-16106/skripsi.renatta.rintan.skripsipbk D/OrderAdapter: []

as you see empty strings, how to do it correctly ?

Comment: So what are you basically want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bring your array declaration out of "inisialisasidata(String email)" scope like this;

```
//Define it like an instance variable
String[] pembeli = new String[]{};
```

Then modify your scope like this

```
rivate void inisialisasidata(String email) {
   pembeli[pembeli.lenght()] = email;

 Log.d("OrderAdapter", Arrays.toString(pembeli));
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: should i call the "pembeli.length()" method ? What does it mean ? cause its red on pembeli.length ()

Comment: That means. you need to insert your new  String at the end of the array.

Comment: i'm not understand :')

Comment: It is a way to add data at the top of the array's children stack